# JomSocial feed images getting height set inline. How do I turn this off?

Tags: css, jomsocial

Images added to the feed are getting a height set inline which resizes the images. Any ideas where I might go in JomSocial configuration to turn this off?

[image: Images in feed are getting height set incorrectly.]

Comment: I just noticed that it only does this if there is more than one photo uploaded to a single post.

Comment: You can always override any inline set attributes by using !important declaration in your custom.css. Like `img {height: auto !important;}`

Comment: My thought exactly. I've added this to the custom.css for the default theme but I don't see it on the site. Do I need to reset something in Joomla for the change to take effect?

Comment: Nevermind. It was the cache! I just cleared it and it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I know it's short answer, but OP in comment accepted it... So...

You can always override any inline set attributes by using !important declaration in your custom.css. Like `img {height: auto !important;}`